# Django CreateView doesn call the success url

Tags: python-3.x, django

My CreateView doesn't call the success url, i've also tried using get_success_url function but still gives the same result, it just returns the form sending the request.

It actually creates the objects in the data base and prints out the entered value, but it never goes to the success url.

This is what i've got

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django_random_id_model import RandomIDModel


DELIVERED_OPTIONS = (
    ("false", "Not Delivered"),
    ("true", "Delivered"),
)


# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    measurements = RichTextField(default='')
    delivered = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=DELIVERED_OPTIONS, default="false")
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
from django import forms
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
from .models import Order


class DeliveryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ["id"]
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'address', 'phone', 'measurements']

    name = forms.CharField(label="Enter your full Name", min_length=5, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Full name please', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label="Enter your Email address", widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter a valid email address', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    address = forms.CharField(label="Enter Your delivery address", widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Delivery address', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(label="Enter your phone number", widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'A valid phone number', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    measurements = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '3'}), required=True)

    def send_email(self):
        pass
```

**URL.PY**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.DeliveryFormView.as_view(), name="delivery"),
    path('order_completed', views.OrderCompleted, name="order_completed"),
]
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from delivery.form import DeliveryForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView
# Create your views here.


class DeliveryFormView(CreateView):
    # context = {
    #     "route": "Contact",
    #     "route_text": "Reach out to us for enquiries and suggestions and complaints"
    # }

    form_class = DeliveryForm
    template_name = 'delivery/delivery_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("order_completed")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        self.send_mail(form.cleaned_data)
        return super(DeliveryFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def send_mail(self, valid_data):
        print(valid_data)


def OrderCompleted(request):
    print("Order Completed")
    # Generate an order number
    # save the order number to the database along with
    # order name, ordered items, total price
    return render(request, "delivery/success.html")
```

Comment: Try to override the `get_success_url()` method instead of using `success_url` attribute.

Comment: I have tried that. It Still didn't work.

Comment: Can you please `print(self.success_url)` and see what is inside it.

Comment: it prints (/delivery/order_completed)

Comment: Try to append `/` in `path('order_completed/'...` then try

Comment: SUCCESS URL: 
/delivery//order_completed
[15/Feb/2023 19:01:55] "POST /delivery/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Feb/2023 19:01:55] "GET /delivery/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19898